# Trying to deploy my nodejs api using reverse proxy method but getting error:

Tags: node.js, iis

I'm trying to deploy my nodejs api on IIS by reverse proxy method but getting error:
**HTTP Error 400.605 - Bad Request
The request cannot be routed because it has reached the Max-Forwards limit. The server may be self-referencing itself in request routing topology.**

The steps i have followed:
1- Created new website on IIS
2- Added a new rule with reverse proxy(Added my hostname i.e localhost:8099 for now)
3- Installed pm2 to running my website constantly

my web.config after rewrite rule:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8099/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: `Created new website on IIS` What's the new site binding information?

Comment: Type: http, IP: Unassigned, PORT: 8099

Answer (score 1):

So you mean that you access the new site through port 8099 and its proxy rule forward request to `http://localhost:8099/{R:1}` ?

If so, please change the binding of the site to other port,or add another binding for it but not use 8099 port, or the target url of proxy rule to other port.

This error is caused by original request and forward request both request for 8099 port.

Comment: So now my error is changed to: 
HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway
A connection with the server could not be established
Most likely causes:
The CGI application did not return a valid set of HTTP errors.
A server acting as a proxy or gateway was unable to process the request due to an error in a parent gateway.

Comment: First try to diable the proxy rule to make sure the nodejs application on IIS can work well. Then check if there any other rewrite rule at server level or site level which may affect the reverse proxy. And if ARR enable the reverse proxy.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/envNB.png  Last is using failed request tracing. Then  check trace log to know what cause this issue.